# Python subprocess only giving 1 output instead of 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, subprocess

I want to generate 2 certificates using openssl and python subprocess, which are `key.pem` and `cert.pem`
and is using the below command to do so.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem
```

this command is working perfectly when executed from the termnial, but when it's being executed from the python script with the help of python subprocess its only giving output the `key.pem` file in the desired directory and not the `cert.pem` file.
Below is the code snippet from the python script:

```
    tempdirname = 'temp_cert/'
    keyname = 'key.pem'
    certname = 'cert.pem'

    expiration_period = '500'
    cmd = ['openssl', 'req', '-newkey', 'rsa:2048', '-nodes', '-keyout', tempdirname+keyname, '-x509', '-days', expiration_period, '-out', tempdirname+certname]
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False
    )
    out, err = p.communicate('\n')
```

I also want the `cert.pem` file is the same directory. What should I do?
I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False
    )
#taking input like this
p.stdin.write("n")    
out, err = p.communicate('\n')
```

removed the following lines and it started working:

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
```